# NPM unhandled rejection

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-start, npm-package

I've just installed npm, but when I try to run it it gives me this error back:

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Expected plugin to either be a plugin instance or a { name, config } object but found ["@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",{"mainConfig":"./webpack.main.config.js","renderer":{"config":"./webpack.renderer.config.js","entryPoints":[{"html":"./src/index.html","js":"./src/renderer.ts","name":"main_window"}]}}]
at /Users/kali/RyuSAK/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/util/plugin-interface.js:32:19
at Array.map ()
at new PluginInterface (/Users/kali/RyuSAK/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/util/plugin-interface.js:16:44)
at exports.default (/Users/kali/RyuSAK/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/util/forge-config.js:160:43)
at async Task.task (/Users/kali/RyuSAK/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/api/start.js:43:35)
at async Task.run (/Users/kali/RyuSAK/node_modules/listr2/dist/index.cjs:978:11)
at async /Users/kali/RyuSAK/node_modules/p-map/index.js:57:22

Can someone help me please?

I tryed preatty much everything I found on the intertet but nothing appened